# Can AI stop attacks like WannaCry?

Tags: applications, cyberterrorism

I have done some research regarding the application of machine learning to cyber-security. After these recent attacks (like [WannaCry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WannaCry_ransomware_attack)), I think that AI-based cyber defense can prevent them. I have also read about research regarding the same in MIT, and that AI can detect more than 80% of malware. Is AI actually so promising in this department?

Comment: Have a look at [2016 Cyber Grand Challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Cyber_Grand_Challenge) too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are projects out there attempting to apply Machine Learning / AI to cyber-security in different ways.  One that I'm familiar with is [Apache Metron](http://metron.apache.org/).  Another related project is [Apache Spot](http://spot.apache.org/).  I think if you read over the docs for these two projects respectively, they will probably give you some good insights on this subject.